# Mendeley API deleted_documents: "No service found for your request"

Tags: api, mendeley

I'm developing an app that interacts with Mendeley API. Retrieving and updating documents work fine, but I fail to retrieve the ID list of deleted documents, as described in [API Reference](http://dev.mendeley.com/methods/#retrieve-list-of-deleted-documents-ids). Instead, I get 404-error, with the message:

```
{
"message": "No service found for your request"
}
```

Looks like this API is not implemented, even though listed in the Reference. Emailing Mendeley API team is of no help (I wrote to them about a different issue 3 months ago, they just don't answer). Anyone worked with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems they just don't update properly the info for developers. From the ["Explore APIs"](https://api.mendeley.com/apidocs/docs#!/documents/getDocuments) section on their site I have found that I should use "deleted_since" URL-parameter, rather than "deleted_documents", as stated in the ["API Reference"](http://dev.mendeley.com/methods/#retrieve-list-of-deleted-documents-ids) section on the same site. The "deleted_since" works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As this thread has opened four years ago, and I was looking for a possible answer to this exact error when using the Mendeley desktop's latest release yesterday, I think it's appropriate to mention such error's occurring to the users. I finally had to reinstall after the total removal of the program from my SSD after importing a lot of references from another reference manager's RIS file. I suppose it has something to do with the server and the desktop app not being completely synced.

It is worth reinstalling if you've had the same problem and have not lost all your library's online material.

Mendeley 1.19.8 on win 10 C64 19044.1706.